# Syntax error in Ruby regexp containing @

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to replace occurrences of special characters like `/`, `:`, etc in a string with `*/*`, `*:*` respectively.

```
str.gsub!(/([;.\\/?:@&=+$,{}|^\[\]`<>#%"'])/, '*\1*')
```

However, I get a `SyntaxError`:

```
`@&' is not allowed as an instance variable name
syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
str.gsub!(/([;.\\/?:@&=+$,{}|^\[\]`<>#%"'])/, '*...
                     ^ (SyntaxError)
```

I tried to define that regexp as a string and use `RegExp.quote(...)` to convert it, but to no avail. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You just forgot to escape the `/` symbol in the regex:

    `str.gsub!(/([;.\\\/?:@&=+$,{}|^\[\]\`<>#%"'])/, '*\1*')`. RoR expects a valid variable name after `@` in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just forgot to escape the `/` symbol in the regex:

```
str.gsub!(/([;.\\\/?:@&=+$,{}|^\[\]`<>#%"'])/, '*\1*')
                 ^
```

Else, a valid variable name after `@` is expected.

Comment: I'd recommend reordering the escaped backslash and escaped-slash in the character-set for readability and easier comprehension.